# Junit Testing with Restfuse and Spring is it possible

Tags: spring, junit

I've spent some time trying to get Restfuse to work with Spring annotations and JUnit but I'm about to give up and try another tool.

Because Restfuse requires @RunWith( HttpJUnitRunner.class ) as Spring requires @RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class), and since only one @Runwith is possible it's hard to see how it can work.

I tried to model the approach/hack of http://www.blog.project13.pl/index.php/coding/1077/runwith-junit4-with-both-springjunit4classrunner-and-parameterized/ but had trouble getting beans from the context as  TestContextManager's get context is not public.

Has anyone had success with this framework and Spring ?